# What's the difference between flush_delayed_work and cancel_delayed_work_sync?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

When shall I use `flush_delayed_work` and `cancel_delayed_work_sync`?

I have following delayed workqueue function:

```c
static void workq_function(struct work_struct *work)
{
    // ...
    queue_delayed_work_on(2, wrkq, work, msecs_to_jiffies(3000));
}
```

Here I'm rescheduling my workqueue again in workqueue. 
Is it a good practice to do like this?

Now i will use the following in `rmmod`:

```c
flush_delayed_work(&work);
cancel_delayed_work_sync(&work);
destroy_workqueue(wrkq);
```

My system hangs after these API's at `rmmod` module.

Comment: Your `workq_function` has a `struct work_queue *` parameter, but you are passing that to a function that expects a `struct delayed_work *` parameter. Is that a typo?